# How to handle special characters in BigQuery external table

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

We have a BigQuery table whose data is coming from a Google Sheet. Occasionally, querying from that sheet breaks because there are cells that start with `+` character.

Example:

```
+search +terms
```

The query result responds with:

[image: BigQuery query result]

[image: Google sheet special char]

Which is not really a formula or something; I just want that text to appear in BigQuery as is.

Manually placing a prefix apostrophe `'` on that cell (or the column where those cells belong) will work for that query instance. But because new data comes automatically at no set schedule, makes that procedure out of question.

[image]

Is there some option in BigQuery that we can set so it interpret such texts literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be aware of the fact that `+` and `#` are actually reserved characters in Google sheets, entering the desired function you want to use in the particular cell.

Mentioned above, If you don't want to supply a predefined formula function after typing one of these special signs, consider adjusting quotation marks (`" ",' '`) to detach the user data.

As long as Bigquery leverages [Sheets data connector](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/connecting-bigquery-and-google-sheets-to-help-with-hefty-data-analysis) to deal with Google spreadsheets it is not equipped with any of instruments to intercept the broken cells `#NAME?`, thus the hand on intervention should be performed in the relevant sheet file in order to align the columns with an actual context.

As a quick solution looking for some concerns, you might be able to fetch the context from `#NAME?` cell adopting `FORMULATEXT()` [function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365792?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472) in neighboring rows as well:

`FORMULATEXT(cell)`

or replace some symbols:

`SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(cell),"=","+")`